# no such index [index: ] when trying to scroll with elasticsearch

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

Since I moved from 2.4 to 5.6, I have an error when using a scroll query :

```
$query = '{
  "scroll" : "1m",
  "scroll_id" : "'. $scrollId .'"
}';

$path = '/_search/scroll';

$responseArray = $this->sendQuery($index, $path, Request::GET, $query);
```

error :

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Elastica\Exception\ResponseException: "no such index [index: ]" at /code/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php line 179

Here the initial query I'm using :

```
$path = 'dataIndex/_search?scroll=1m';

$query = sprintf(
  '{
   "size" : 500,
   "stored_fields": "_source"
   }'
);
```

And how I call my scroll function

```
$hits = $this->getElasticNextScroll($this->dataIndex, $hits['_scroll_id']);
```

One of the solution I tried was to send the request with POST but I got another error :

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Elastica\Exception\ResponseException: "String index out of range: 0" at /code/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php line 179

EDIT SOLUTION :

the path '/_search/scroll' worked in 2.4 but doesn't work anymore in 5.3. You need to remove the first / : '_search/scroll'

Comment: What is the value of $index above this line:

$responseArray = $this->sendQuery($index, $path, Request::GET, $query);

?

Comment: see my comment bellow, I send the same index both in the initial query and the scroll one BUT it work only for the first one

Answer (score 0):

specify what value is passed to $index and what is included in the Request :: GET function

Answer (score 0):

```
Index {#9208 
-originalName: null
-typeCache: []
#_name: "index_data"
#_client: Client {#9234
-indexCache: array:1 [
  "index_data" => Index {#9208}
]
-stopwatch: Stopwatch {#157
...
```

And here the stack error I have :

> [1] Elastica\Exception\ResponseException: no such index [index: ] at n/a in /code/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php line 179
>
> at Elastica\Transport\Http->exec(object(Request), array('connection' => array('config' => array('headers' => array(), 'curl' => array()), 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '9200', 'logger' => false, 'ssl' => false, 'compression' => false, 'retryOnConflict' => '0', 'enabled' => true))) in /code/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Request.php line 193
>
> at Elastica\Request->send() in /code/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php line 674
>
> at Elastica\Client->request('/_search/scroll', 'GET', '{ "scroll" : "1m", "scroll_id" : "DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoBAAAAAAAAAPfFnF2VnFBRzFWU0RTaTAwVVZLSl9UU2cAAAAAAAAD3RZxdlZxQUcxVlNEU2kwMFVWS0pfVFNnAAAAAAAAA-AWcXZWcUFHMVZTRFNpMDBVVktKX1RTZwAAAAAAAAPeFnF2VnFBRzFWU0RTaTAwVVZLSl9UU2c=" }', array(), 'application/json') in /code/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/Elastica/Client.php line 50
>
> at FOS\ElasticaBundle\Elastica\Client->request('/_search/scroll', 'GET', '{ "scroll" : "1m", "scroll_id" : "DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoBAAAAAAAAAPfFnF2VnFBRzFWU0RTaTAwVVZLSl9UU2cAAAAAAAAD3RZxdlZxQUcxVlNEU2kwMFVWS0pfVFNnAAAAAAAAA-AWcXZWcUFHMVZTRFNpMDBVVktKX1RTZwAAAAAAAAPeFnF2VnFBRzFWU0RTaTAwVVZLSl9UU2c=" }') in /code/src/AppBundle/Repository/ElasticSearch/BaseElasticSearchRepository.php line 22